# Why does a decorator function have a return value?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Consider the following example.

```py
def decorator(function_to_decorate):
    def wrapper():
        print('Entering', function_to_decorate.__name__)
        function_to_decorate()
        print('Exiting', function_to_decorate.__name__)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def func():
    print("Original function.")

func()
```

As the `@decorator` syntax is just the shorthand for `func = my_decorator(func)`, it is logical that `my_decorator` must return something. My question is: why are decorators defined in this way and not without return value: `my_decorator(func)`? What is the purpose of returning the wrapper function `wrapper`?

---

### EDIT

How does a decorator do more than a simple wrapper?

```py
def wrapper(function_to_decorate):
    print('Entering', function_to_decorate.__name__)
    function_to_decorate()
    print('Exiting', function_to_decorate.__name__)
```

```py
def func():
    print("Original function.")
```

```py
wrapper(func)
```

Comment: If they didn't, then `func` would still refer to the function you defined.

Comment: @kaya3 But then why is
```
def wrapper(function_to_decorate):
        print('Entering', function_to_decorate.__name__)
        function_to_decorate()
        print('Exiting', function_to_decorate.__name__)

wrapper(func)
```
not sufficient?

Comment: Do code blocks work in comments?

Comment: Code in comments doesn't work well, you can use single backticks for short `pieces of code`. Often it's better to [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine if you could apply a decorator to a regular variable assignment, like this:

```py
def add1(x):
    return x + 1

@add1
number = 5
```

The analogous behaviour to a function decorator would be like this:

```py
number = 5
number = add1(number)
```

This would result in assigning the value `6` to the variable `number`. Now imagine that the decorator was just called without returning anything:

```py
number = 5
add1(number)
```

There is no way this code could possibly assign `6` to the variable `number`, because `number` is [passed by value, not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference); in Python, a function cannot assign a new value to a variable in a completely different scope which it has no access to.

---

A `def` statement is really a kind of assignment; it assigns the function to the name you defined it with. For example, the function definition `def func(): pass` compiles to bytecode that does a `STORE_NAME`, i.e. an assignment:

```
  1     0 LOAD_CONST         0 (<code object func at ...>)
        3 LOAD_CONST         1 ('func')
        6 MAKE_FUNCTION      0
        9 STORE_NAME         0 (func)
```

So the behaviour of function decorators works the same way as above, for the same reason; the decorator function cannot reassign a new function to the variable `func` in a completely different scope, because `func` is passed by value to the decorator, not by reference.

The `func = decorator(func)` equivalence is actually a bit misleading. To be fully correct, when you use a decorator, the function you defined in the `def` statement is passed *directly* to the decorator, not assigned to the local name `func` before being passed. Here's the bytecode:

```
  1     0 LOAD_NAME          0 (decorate)
        3 LOAD_CONST         0 (<code object func at ...>)
        6 LOAD_CONST         1 ('func')
        9 MAKE_FUNCTION      0
       12 CALL_FUNCTION      1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
       15 STORE_NAME         1 (func)
```

Step-by-step:

- The `decorate` function is loaded onto the stack,
- The code object for `func` is loaded onto the stack, then the string `'func'`, then the `MAKE_FUNCTION` instruction turns those two into a function which is left on the stack.
- The `CALL_FUNCTION` instruction calls the `decorate` function (which is still on the stack) with one argument, the `func` function.
- Whatever the `decorate` function returns is left on the stack, and assigned to the name `func` by the `STORE_NAME` instruction.

So if the `decorator` function didn't return anything, there would be nothing to assign to the name `func` - not even the original function as in the `def` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. See my edited post for a related question that came to my mind.

Comment: The difference is that with a decorator, you have changed the behaviour of the function bound to that name, so that when it is called you get the new behaviour. In the second case you just passed the function to another function which called it immediately, but the function's name is still bound to the original function with its own behaviour.